When I press numbers on the keyboard, the collections are hidden
I think I clicked something and now when I click 1 or 2 in object mode, the collections in the outliner disappear. how do I fix it and what did I click? for example, I press 2 and my entire collection goes into the "hide in viewport" mode

What you are describing is normal behavior in Object Mode. Unfortunately I can't find the documentation about it.
To make all the collections visible toggle them on by pressing Shift and the keyboard number of each collection. Or, you can have one collection visible at a time by pressing just the keyboard number of that collection. Then, when you want the others visible press Shift and their numbers to turn them on.
You can find these keystrokes by searching in Key-Binding. In this case number 1:

